# Remove div inline style on device rotation

Tags: jquery

I am working on a search form that shows expanded on desktop and collapsed on mobile devices. All is ok except one issue that i noticed.

To see the issue, please replicate these steps in https://jsfiddle.net/jrnvbvb5/

Open with firebug in firefox, change the window size to 1685px width (or close) and if you rotate the window, extended search bar is replaced just by the search icon. No matter how many times you change device orientation, this works ok.

Now, change view to portrait and click on search button (to expand bellow the search form). Click again to close the dropdown and hide the search bar and NEXT, rotate to landscape and the extended search will not show anymore.

When i inspect with firebug i see  which prevents the search form to appear. So, how can i lose that style="display: none; when i change view to portrait?

```
$(".dropdown").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-values").fadeOut(500);
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").not(this).find(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
});
$(document).click(function(event) {
  $(".dropdown-values").fadeOut(500);
  $(".dropdown-title").removeClass("activated");
});
$(".dropdown-title").click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings(".dropdown-values").fadeToggle(500);

  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.dropdown-title').toggleClass("activated");
});
$(".icon-search").click(function(event) {
  $(this).siblings(".search-form-container").fadeToggle(500);

  $(this).parents(".searchBar-form").find('.icon-search').toggleClass("activated");
});
```

```css
.show_hide {
  display: none;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 300;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
.page-nav-right {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
.searchBar-form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 40%;
  display: block;
}
}
.dropdown {
  background: #313654;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.dropdown:hover {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-values {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
}
.activated {
  background: orange;
}
.dropdown-title {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
}
.dropdown-values {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100%;
  background: #3f4c6b;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.dropdown-values a {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-values a:HOVER {
  background: #dedede;
  display: block;
}
.search input[type=submit] {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  width: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
  opacity: 0.5;
  outline: 0;
}
.search input[type=submit]:hover {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  -khtml-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.search input {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 7px 87px 6px 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.search {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.search .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  color: #fff;
}
.search .icon i {
  font-size: 21px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}
.search .separator {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 43px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(236, 236, 236) 0%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 50%, rgb(236, 236, 236) 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(236, 236, 236) 0%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 50%, rgb(236, 236, 236) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(236, 236, 236) 0%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 50%, rgb(236, 236, 236) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(236, 236, 236) 0%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 50%, rgb(236, 236, 236) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(236, 236, 236) 0%, rgb(204, 204, 204) 50%, rgb(236, 236, 236) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(236, 236, 236)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(204, 204, 204)), color-stop(1, rgb(236, 236, 236)));
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#33000000, endColorstr=#33000000);
}
.search .search-options {
  z-index: 999;
}
.search-options-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 45px;
  top: 2px;
}
.search-options-toggle i {
  background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.search-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.search-form-container {
  background: #3f4c6b none repeat scroll 0 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 699px) {
  .icon-search {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 36px;
  }
  .searchBar-form {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .search-form-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .search .icon-search {
    display: block;
  }
  .icon-search {
    display: none;
  }
  .searchBar-form {
    position: relative;
  }
  .search-form-container {
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="logo" role="navigation"></div>
  <div class="page-nav-right" role="navigation"></div>
  <div class="searchBar-form">
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    <div class="search-form-container">
      <form class="search" method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
        <input type="text" class="text-input" size="21" maxlength="120">
        <div class="dropdown search-options">
          <a class="dropdown-title search-options-toggle" href="#/">
            <i class="icon-cut"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-values search-options-container">
            <li>OPTION 1</li>
            <li>OPTION 2</li>
            <li>OPTION 3</li>
            <li>OPTION 4</li>
            <li>OPTION 5</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="separator"></div>
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="icon-search"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Couldn't you loose the JavaScript and only use CSS?

Comment: It would be ideal but will not work as it should because dropdown on click via css which works in any device/browser i could not find. The closeset thing i found was http://koen.kivits.com/articles/pure-css-menu/ which does not work perfect in the end (see author mentions)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution (in case others need it)
replace  $(this).siblings(".search-form-container").fadeToggle(500) with toggleClass("activated") and in style add display:block !important to .activated